# Change GeoServer data directory

Tags: geoserver

I've installed GeoServer on my pc using the web archive and the OS of this pc is Ubuntu 18.04. I can use GeoServer without problem but I need to change the default data directory of GeoServer.

I've followed [this official method](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#web-archive) modifying the context parameter to do this but withouth fortune.

What is the right way to change that folder?

I need to use `/home/user-name/GeoServerDataFolder` instead of `/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/00a90b48100f8ef4f8c452a79bf9000c) the procedure that I've used to install GeoServer, I'm using Tomcat9.

Comment: did you restart tomcat after you changed the context variable? what does the log file say when it restarts?

Comment: I've used  `systemctl stop tomcat9.service` and `systemctl start tomcat9.service`. Where I can find the log file?

Comment: in the logs directory of the data directory or in the tomcat logs /var/log/tomcat/

Comment: Inside the log I see this message `Found Servlet context parameter GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to /home/user-name/GeoServerDataFolder , which is not writeable`

Comment: that is probably a clue - the user that is running GeoServer **must** have write permission for the data directory.

Comment: My user is `user-name` and I've the full control of that folder. Maybe I need to do this also for `tomcat9`? Before the installation of Tomcat9 I've followed this procedure: `useradd -r tomcat9`, `mkdir /usr/local/tomcat9` and 'chown -R tomcat9:tomcat9 /usr/local/tomcat9'. I've described all here: https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/00a90b48100f8ef4f8c452a79bf9000c

Comment: Who "you" are is irrelevant - "who" is running tomcat is important.

Comment: Thank you! If you add an answer instead of the comments I can vote you and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure that the user that is running tomcat can write to the new data directory.